# Не найден модуль Installation of Tensorflow в RStudio

Tags: r, keras, tensorflow

Пытаюсь запустить пакеты Keras и Tensorflow в Rstudio

Ввожу install.packages("keras")
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

Затем при попытке создать нейронную сеть с помощью модуля keras_model_sequential()
model<-keras_model_sequential()

Появляется следующая ошибка

```
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_R\python.exe
 C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_R\python.exe
 C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.

Но при введении кода install_tensorflow()  (при том, что пакет "tensorflow" уже установлен) появляется ошибка:

Error in conda_install(envname, packages, conda = conda, ...) : 
  unused argument (python_version = "3.6")
```

Прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и надежный способ

```
library(keras)
install(keras)
is_keras_available()
```

TF будет установлен в окружение

```
C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/r-minconda/envs/r-tensorflow
```

Если Вы хотите установить TF в уже существующее окружение, нужна будет дополнительная гимнастика и в будущем дополнительная головная боль. Для начинающих не рекомендую этот путь.
Удачи

Comment: Спасибо Вам за информацию. А что означает install(keras)?
При вводе этой команды появляется ошибка вида: Error in install(keras) : could not find function "install" RStudio обнаруживает только следующие команды: install.packages("keras") install_keras()

Comment: Конечно install_keras(). У меня описка. Кроме того, TF и Keras могут установиться в окружение r-reticulate. Пробуйте

Answer (score -1):

Понял, спасибо.
Но, к сожалению, проблема с загрузкой keras осталась. Я ввожу код

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
is_keras_available()
```

и запускаю его. Появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Error in install_keras() : 
  You should call install_keras() only in a fresh R session that has not yet initialized Keras and TensorFlow (this is to avoid DLL in use errors during installation)
```

Соответственно, после команды `is_keras_available()` выводится текст `FALSE`.

Если сначала ввести команды

```
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
```

а затем ввести

```
    library(keras)
    install_keras()
    is_keras_available()
```

то появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Error in conda_install(envname, packages, conda = conda, ...) : 
  unused argument (python_version = "3.6")
```